# How to correcly compile and run UM7 downloaded from git

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

i tried to install UM7 drivers on my RPI with Ubuntu Mate (1.12.1). I installed ros-kinetics library (all).
Unfortunatelly, the kinetic package have not um7 library for apt-get. Then i download  sources from git ( https://github.com/ros-drivers/um7.git), compile and install it.

Simly, steps:

git clone xxxx

mkdir build

cd build

cmake ../ (sucessfully)

make (sucessfully)

make install (sucessfully)

rosrun um7 um7_driver _port:=/dev/ttyAMA0 : [rospack] Error: package 'um7' not found

Any sugestions where is a problem and how to run UM7?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251946/how-to-correcly-compile-and-run-um7-downloaded-from-git/) by [Wiew](https://answers.ros.org/users/29043/wiew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you did is possible, but I don't recommend it if you just started out.

It's probably easier to create a [catkin workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces), put the `um7` package in that and build it using `catkin_make`. If successful, `source devel/setup.bash`. Then try your `rosrun ..` command again.

See [Creating a workspace for catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) for a tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [B Dhruva](https://answers.ros.org/users/39961/b-dhruva/) on 2019-02-13**:
Hello.. I am getting error no such file or directory when I do perform rosrun..... command.
Followed the same steps as mentioned above.

It would be helpful if I can get pointer to this help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
Was the compilation successful? Did you see any errors?

If it was successful: try running `rospack profile` *afer* having `source`d the `devel/setup.bash`.

**Comment by [B Dhruva](https://answers.ros.org/users/39961/b-dhruva/) on 2019-02-13**:
Yes compilation was successful. after rospack profile following error.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::run time error'
what() locale::facet ::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)

it is not able to find package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
Well if `rospack` throws an error then it wouldn't have run. So effectively the situation hasn't changed.

**Comment by [B Dhruva](https://answers.ros.org/users/39961/b-dhruva/) on 2019-02-13**:
Can you let me know how to debug this? I also tried to install um7 using sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-um7. when I am trying to perform rosrun um7 um7_driver it shows error no file or directory found.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
I would guess first make sure the files are actually there, and that `um7_driver` is actually a binary/ros node.

What is the output of `ls -al /opt/ros/indigo/lib/um7`?

**Comment by [B Dhruva](https://answers.ros.org/users/39961/b-dhruva/) on 2019-02-13**:
Hello Dhoorn,
please find the output below:

```
administrator@administrator:~$ ls -al /opt/ros/indigo/lib/um7
total 124
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Feb 11 05:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 56 root root  12288 Feb 12 07:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 109720 May 17  2018 um7_driver
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
Seeing as the node is there and you're running into `rospack` issues with crashes, I would suggest to post a new question. Please clearly describe what is not working, mention the `rospack profile` crash, show the `ls -al` output and refer to this question.

**Comment by [B Dhruva](https://answers.ros.org/users/39961/b-dhruva/) on 2019-02-13**:
#q315560 posted. Thank you :-)